# How does C# properties really work?

Tags: c#, properties

If I have:

```
class Test
{
    private Vector2 v;

    public Vector2 Velocity
    {
        get { return v; }
        set { v = value; }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Test t = new Test();

t.Velocity = new Vector2(2, 2);
t.Velocity.Normalize();
Console.WriteLine(t.Velocity); // here not normalized

Vector2 tmp = t.Velocity;
tmp.Normalize();
t.Velocity = tmp;
Console.WriteLine(t.Velocity); // here normalized

Console.Read();
```

Why if I directly try to call Normalize on the property Velocity it is not normalized
and with a tmp Vector2 it is?

P.S.
Vector2 is a struct:

```
public struct Vector2 : IEquatable<Vector2>
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    ...
    public void Normalize() {...}
}
```

Comment: Vector2 seems to be a Value type. You should read [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: @noah1989 Then how would `tmp` be normalized, as the result of `tmp.Normalize()` isn't re-assigned to `tmp` either?

Comment: Actually we need more code. How are `Test` and `Vector2` defined?

Comment: I edited the post showing the def of Vector2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List item

I guess that in your case `Vector2` is a value type (struct).

In that case, in your first example, you will get a copy of `v` returned by the get part of the `Velocity` property and you will call `Normalize` on the copy, effectively doing nothing, since the copy goes out of scope after the call to Normalize.

If Vector2 had been a reference type (class), this would have worked as you expected without having  to create a new object first, and then assign it using the set part of `Velocity`.

Remember that mutable structs are [evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx). If you always make your structs immutable, you should not get into problems like this.

Answer (score 6):

I **suppose** that the question in **not** related to the actually how properties are maneged in `.NET Framework`, but how `value types` are managed inside .NET Framework.

I worked with CAD kernels and, even if it's not clear from the code provided, I **suppose** that `Vector2` is a `struct` (usually it is for speedup in fast allocations/rendering), so it is a `value type`

When you `Normalize(...)` a value type you normalize a **copy** of it, that's why in the second case it works, cause *first* you normalize **copy**, *after* assign it to **original** value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: it depends on **how** Normalize(..) is implemented. I have no idea.

Comment: according to the explained behaviour, I would **suppose** Normalize(..) creates a copy of the Vector2 type somehow.

Comment: actually I take that back - of course there is a subtlety that is entirely explained by the value type behaviour - by accessing through the property getter the Normalise call is indeed operating on a copy of the data and therefore can never write back to the original data; even if the Normalise operation writes back to the struct's own data (which we hope it doesn't :))

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - We hope doesn't, but since the second example works, we know it does ;)

Comment: Usually they define some Math namepsace where for value types accept REFs of them, so consumer of API calls the function and gets *changed* value as expected. Have this kind of situations, like here **to me** always seems kind of wired, cause if I call a function on object (value type or not) and I know that function should change somethign in it, object **has** to be changed after the call.

Answer (score 5):

If `Vector2` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), the property getter will return a new copy, and applying `Normalize()` to that copy will not impact the original.

In other words, `v` and `t.Velocity` are not the same object, so changes made to one are not reflected in the other.

If `Vector2` was a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), you would obtain the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your `Vector2` it sounds like it is a value type. You are therefore not given a reference to your `Velocity` but a copy of it.